# How to remove rows with null values from a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have small dataframe with null values in columns.

| Movie | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Avatar | 178 |
| Spectre |  |
| John Carter | 132 |
| Tangled |  |
| Titanic | 195 |

I can remove rows with null values for one column at a time with this command -

`df.drop(df[df['duration'].isnull()].index)`

But, suppose I had a large dataframe with hundreds of columns with null row values, then removing null row values for one column at a time is not possible.

What should be my approach in such a case?

Comment: would a simple ```df.dropna(0)``` suffice? 
But having a large dataset and dropping all rows with a minimum of a single NULL value might leave you with no dataset at all

Comment: So in that case what should be my approach to data cleaning (removing null row values).

Comment: btw a reason why your questions get downvoted might be your use of pictures and/or links. Having code/datasets in a code block makes questions easier and quicker to understand

Comment: If you don't need any rows with missing values this is fine. (adding the reason for cleaning in your question also helps with geting answers). If you want to get rid of the null values because a calculation or a algorithm doesn't work, consider filling the Null values with a column average, or a static number like 0 or 1. The kind of cleaning always depends on what you want to do with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Omniswitcher commented, `df.drop()` will work.

```
pd.read_excel('Movie.xlsx').dropna(axis=0)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: didn't have time to recreate/try it myself, thanks for the confirmation!